# Can't access virtualhost with ServerName on Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Tags: apache, unix, virtualhost

My vhost.conf

```
NameVirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80

<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/wordpress
  ServerName blog.xxx.jp

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/javascript text/css application/json
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{cookie}i\" \"%{Set-cookie}o\"" cookie
  CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/access_log-last /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/access_log-%Y-%U" cookie
  ErrorLog  "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/error_log-last /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/error_log-%Y-%U"

  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/wordpress>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/shop.xxx.jp/eccube-2.12.2/html
  ServerName shop.xxx.jp
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/javascript text/css application/json
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{cookie}i\" \"%{Set-cookie}o\"" cookie
  CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/www/vhosts/shop.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/access_log-last /var/www/vhosts/shop.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/access_log-%Y-%U" cookie
  ErrorLog  "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/www/vhosts/shop.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/error_log-last /var/www/vhosts/shop.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/error_log-%Y-%U"

  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/shop.xxx.jp/eccube-2.12.2/html>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 22 2013 11:19:58

I can access shop.xxx.jp, but can't blog.xxx.jp (it's not pinging). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried to delete the second part & my vhost.conf start looks like this ⬇

```
NameVirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80

<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/wordpress
  ServerName blog.xxx.jp

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/javascript text/css application/json
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{cookie}i\" \"%{Set-cookie}o\"" cookie
  CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/access_log-last /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/access_log-%Y-%U" cookie
  ErrorLog  "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/error_log-last /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/statistics/logs/error_log-%Y-%U"

  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/blog.xxx.jp/wordpress>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

& the site with Wordpress starts to work on this url -> shop.xxx.jp
Maybe, it'll be a hint or something :)

UPDATE
I run -> dig blog.xxx.jp

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.6 <<>> blog.salaf.jp
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 19121
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;blog.xxx.jp.           IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xxx.jp.     10674   IN  SOA ns36.joeswebhosting.net. support-    tech.joeswebhosting.net. 2013032104 86400 7200 3600000 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr  9 10:45:56 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103
```

Comment: *can't blog.xxx.jp (it's not pinging)*. So, is `blog.xxx.jp` a valid DNS name or not?

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question. It looks like its not valid :) How can I fix it? Thank you :)